# Writingminds ffmpeg 64 bit architecture support

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMpeg in one of my project for audio video mixing and it is working fine.

Now I have requirement for 64-bit architecture support so i have generated .so files for 64-bit architecture support. Now the problem is like in java code there is a class CpuArch.java in which some architecture are define with some alphanumeric value like below:

x86("0dd4dbad305ff197a1ea9e6158bd2081d229e70e"),
ARMv7("871888959ba2f063e18f56272d0d98ae01938ceb")

Now I have to add two more value for ARMv8 and x86_64. From where I got these alphanumeric values.
And one more thing like assets folder contain ffmpeg files During .so file generation nothing updates in assets folder so how could I generate those files for other architecture as well.

Please help.

I followed this library for audio video mixing : https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: did you resolve the issue? i am stuck with the same